# How to remove font family with Laravel Inertia/Vue & tailwind

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, inertiajs

These two lines is injected in Head automatically.

How to remove them? Laravel Inertia/Vue & Tailwind

```
<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
<link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
```

this is `tailwind.config.js`

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/js/**/*.vue',
    ],
    darkMode: 'class',


    theme: {
        extend: {
            // fontFamily: {
            //     sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            // },
        },
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
};
```

Comment: I think the code is in the `resources/views/welcome.blade.php` file. Remove it from there.
[Source Code](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

Comment: @linktoahref Thanks. The exact file is resources/views/app.blade.php. You give a good clue.